# Were any resources from Deep Space Nine utilized in the search for Voyager?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-eu

The USS Voyager was on a mission dealing with the Maquis in the Badlands when it disappeared (in 2371). Since that is essentially in the local neighborhood of Deep Space Nine and I'm assuming Starfleet would search for the missing ship, were any resources from the station, such as some runabouts or the Defiant (launched in 2370), utilized in searching for Voyager? Did Deep Space Nine serve as the command center for the search?

I'll accept material from the EU, as I don't recall seeing any mention of Voyager during the *Deep Space Nine* series.

Answer (score 8):

<sub>*I'm answering by only having seen the relevant TV shows, I know nothing about the expanded universe of the novels, comics, and so on.

And I'm mainly going by memory, it's been a while since I have watched these series, so I could be not entirely accurate.*</sub>

---

## Very likely, no

I don't recall any references to the USS Voyager in [*Deep Space Nine*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine), and the only time that the station is shown (and possibly mentioned?) on [*Voyager*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Voyager) is in the very first episode, when the ship commanded by Janeway leaves the station to hunt down the Maquis.

We don't have any information about the early search for the missing Voyager (or other ships like the [USS Equinox](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Equinox)); from what we know, Starfleet could have considered it as having been destroyed while navigating inside the [Badlands](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Badlands). It was known to be a dangerous region, that featured intense plasma storms and gravitational anomalies; difficulties inside it were not uncommon.

Very probably, some standard procedures were enacted, but it is highly unlikely that the effort was prolonged after they realized that the ship could not be found anywhere inside the Badlands: they could not possibly know that these ships were displaced in the Delta Quadrant without any further information.

It should be noted that [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Voyager#The_Pathfinder_Project) reports that the Voyager was declared "officially lost" in 2473, two years after its disappearance, indicating that at least some basic effort was performed, but we don't know to what extent; it is plausible that they were just following the formal rules and that this was a somewhat legal time after a missing ship should be declared lost.

Then we have to consider that Deep Space Nine already had its very high share of duties, responsibilities and troubles:

- it was a foreign station that had to be adapted to work with Federation and Bajoran technologies and procedures;
- it was located near the Bajoran Wormhole, making it the main outpost for everything related to it and the Gamma Quadrant;
- it served as something similar to an overseer to the political situation over Bajor, and like a mediator between them and the Cardassians;
- when the Dominion War broke, it was located in the front line and was nearly exclusively a war station at that point;
- on-screen, we never hear about the Voyager, and are never given any detail about a supposed responsibility of the station on the search of the lost vessels, especially for what concerns having a leading role; if that would be the case, the senior officers that we always see on-screen should have been surely involved in this.

On the later seasons of *Voyager*, we see that a more or less stable communication channel was established between Voyager and Starfleet in the Alpha Quadrant. These communications were managed by the [Pathfinder Project](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Pathfinder_Project), based in the [Communications Research Center](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Communications_Research_Center), located in San Francisco.

---

**Summarizing, it seems that early on there was not a serious effort to find the Voyager, and for many reasons Deep Space Nine was not much involved in this, if not completely extraneous. When a detailed program to communicate with the Voyager and rescue it was put in place, it was managed from Earth.**

Comment: sidebar: Tuvok did appear in a mirror episode of DS9